# CosmosDB - mongoDB - Table not formed on Azure Portal, but activity log is showing status success

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to Azure Database, I am using cosmosDB (MongoDB), I have connected to the CosmosDB, via string URL. When I am storing data through the collection it is not showing any exception on my application infact it is showing status success when I check the logs, but it is not visible on data explorer. When I am calling the complete data I am able to retrieve it also..
Only problem is that it is not visible on the mongoDb console neither it is visible on data explorer.

[data explorer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hskh.png)

Comment: What data explorer are you referring to? It would help if you showed a screenshot. That said: If you have collections created within your database, they are all accessible via the Azure portal.

Comment: Actually I have created a database and then when I am running the application it saving the data and I can even retrieve the data but is not showing the data on  Azure portal as well as console..

Comment: you can check the screenshot here https://fin360.slack.com/files/prashant/F6REWSU8M/mongodb.png

Comment: Please edit your question and embed the screenshot. Nobody should have to go to your Slack to see it. And it's trivial to embed an image: `![description](url)`

Comment: Just to second @DavidMakogon, who will create slack account just to see your image? see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oops sorry for above I have added the image..

Answer (score 0):

To see the data, click on the Documents node of the testTable database in the Data Explorer (records are called Documents in DocumentDB).

Here's an example:

[image]